# Editor Window screenshot

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor, unity-editor

I want to capture a screenshot from a custom EditorWindow that I'm using as a LevelEditor for a game I'm working on, but i'm not sure on how to do it.

What I want is to capture the EditorWindow, NOT the game view or the scene view.

Can you help me?
Thanks!

Edit: I want to take screenshots by code, when pressing a GUILayout.Button :)

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: I think he means the functionality to capture the editorwindow and save it to a imagefile, like Shaderforge uses. See https://shaderforge.userecho.com/communities/1/topics/930-quickly-take-screenshot-of-entire-node-grid-at-appropriate-resolution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made a script for this using `InternalEditorUtility.ReadScreenPixel`.

At first I actually had it as you requested on a `GUILayout.Button` but decided to instead provide a more general solution here which is completely independent from the `EditorWindow` itself. 
(You could still call `EditorScreenshotExtension.Screenshot();` from the `GUILayout.Button` anyway.)

I rather added a global `MenuItem` with ShortCut so you actually can take a screenshot of **any** currently active (last clicked/focused) `EditorWindow`!

**EditorScreenshotExtension.cs**

```c#
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public static class EditorScreenshotExtension
{
    [MenuItem("Screenshot/Take Screenshot %#k")]
    private static void Screenshot()
    {
        // Get actvive EditorWindow
        var activeWindow = EditorWindow.focusedWindow;

        // Get screen position and sizes
        var vec2Position = activeWindow.position.position;
        var sizeX = activeWindow.position.width;
        var sizeY = activeWindow.position.height;

        // Take Screenshot at given position sizes
        var colors = InternalEditorUtility.ReadScreenPixel(vec2Position, (int)sizeX, (int)sizeY);

        // write result Color[] data into a temporal Texture2D
        var result = new Texture2D((int)sizeX, (int)sizeY);
        result.SetPixels(colors);

        // encode the Texture2D to a PNG
        // you might want to change this to JPG for way less file size but slightly worse quality
        // if you do don't forget to also change the file extension below
        var bytes = result.EncodeToPNG();

        // In order to avoid bloading Texture2D into memory destroy it
        Object.DestroyImmediate(result);

        // finally write the file e.g. to the StreamingAssets folder
        var timestamp = System.DateTime.Now;
        var stampString = string.Format("_{0}-{1:00}-{2:00}_{3:00}-{4:00}-{5:00}", timestamp.Year, timestamp.Month, timestamp.Day, timestamp.Hour, timestamp.Minute, timestamp.Second);
        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Screenshot" + stampString + ".png"), bytes);

        // Refresh the AssetsDatabase so the file actually appears in Unity
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();

        Debug.Log("New Screenshot taken");
    }
}
```

---

Since it uses `UnityEditor` and `UnityEditorInternal` make sure to place it in a folder called `Editor` to exlude it from any builds.

---

After importing it to your project simply use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to create a Screenshot of the currently active EditorWindow.

Screenshots are placed as PNG file in `Assets/StreamingAssets` with a timestamp in the name.

It will also add an entry to the top menu of the UniytEditor.

---

The current shortcut was just a random one which is not used so far. you can change it in `[MenuItem(Screenshot/Take Screenshot %#k)]` following the [MenuItem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html) docs

> To create a hotkey you can use the following special characters:
>
> - **%** (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>cmd</kbd> on macOS)
> - **#** (<kbd>shift</kbd>)
> - **&** (<kbd>alt</kbd>)
> - If no special modifier key combinations are required the key can be given after an underscore.
>
> For example to create a menu with hotkey shift-alt-g use "MyMenu/Do Something #&g". To create a menu with hotkey <kbd>g</kbd> and no key modifiers pressed use **_** like "MyMenu/Do Something _g".
>
> Some special keyboard keys are supported as hotkeys, for example "#LEFT" would map to shift-left. The keys supported like this are: LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN, F1 .. F12, HOME, END, PGUP, PGDN.
>
> A hotkey text must be preceded with a space character ("MyMenu/Do_g" won't be interpreted as hotkey, while "MyMenu/Do _g" will).

---

Here in action - the first time I simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> after having focused the `Project` view last; the second time I focus the `Inspector` and use the menu item to take the screenshot

[image]