# Unity How do I capture GameView in my EditorWindow

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple leveleditor window for my game and I want to capture GameView image to that leveleditor window. I'm using ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture() but it gives the image of leveleditor window, I also try Texture2d.ReadPixels but it gives the same result.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54543469/7111561). I wrote a script that can capture **any** window that is currently focused.

You could easily adopt it to allways make the `GameView` the captured window. For example using reflection like this ([source](https://answers.unity.com/questions/915069/want-to-get-the-location-of-the-gameview-window.html))

```c#
public static EditorWindow GetMainGameView()
{
    var assembly = typeof(EditorWindow).Assembly;
    var type = assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView");
    var gameview = EditorWindow.GetWindow(type);
    return gameview;
}
```

and replacing

```c#
var activeWindow = EditorWindow.focusedWindow;
```

with

```c#
var activeWindow = GetMainGameView();
```

---

Note that this will open a new `GameView` window if none was there yet.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ?

`var activeWindow = GetMainGameView();`