# What is the "selectedSizeIndex" for unity 2023+ (for changing editor viewer size)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I have been using https://github.com/aktsk/screenshot-for-app-store/ for taking screenshot in game in Unity, however, I updated to Unity 2023 (Beta) and this not long works.
I susspect the variable used to control the size of the screen is now no longer support.

This is the exact line I susspect
.

```
PropertyInfo selectedSizeIndex = Types.gameView.GetProperty("selectedSizeIndex", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
selectedSizeIndex.SetValue(gameView, index, null);
```

Another way to ask the question,
Has anyone found an alternative way to change the screen size in unity editor mode, for example to take a screenshot, or have anyone found/created a screenshot tool in editor mode that will take screenshots for mobile store?

The Size I am revering to is the editor view of the game, not the game itself.

Did I mention this is for Unity 2023+

Imported the screenshot-for-app-store (https://github.com/aktsk/screenshot-for-app-store/) in Unity <2022 (WORKS)
Click the menu item "Take Screenshot" (WORKS)
Upgraged to Unity 2023
Click menu item "Take Screenshot" (ERROR)

Comment: Would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663073/editor-window-screenshot answered quite a while ago but it should still work the same way without any internal magic .. It just uses the current sizes without actively setting those though .. not tested of course in 2023 but I would expect that stuff to still work the same way

Answer (score 0):

Soo I know I'm almost a year late to this but I figured it out. Thought I'd share. Just adjust the Binding flag from NonPublic to Public and it starts working again.

Don't exactly know when the change happened but when I checked the source code from [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/GameView/GameView.cs), it seems now the property is public. Here's the changed line:

```
PropertyInfo selectedSizeIndex = typeof(Editor).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView").GetProperty("selectedSizeIndex", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
selectedSizeIndex.SetValue(gameView, index, null);
```